# How can I set the imageview with Picasso library?

Tags: android, picasso

I have my GridViewAdapter and I want to set an imageview with whatI load from Picasso . The image is loaded , but is not showing in GridView , only if I clicked on the image will show the image in full screen like I did to be if I click on it.. Every answer will be apreaciated. Thanks.

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
    // Locate the TextView in gridview_item.xml
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
     image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position

    Picasso.with(parent.getContext()).load(filepath[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);

    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position


    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
  //  image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: Picasso.with(activity).load(filepath[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);

Comment: @GeorgeThomas can you help me with a view holder pattern please, because I'm a newbie in android . Thanks

Comment: please share the code where you set the adapter

Comment: Write code, where you created GridViewAdapter in your activity. And try use activity.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image path is local then you have to use file

```
File file = new File(filepath[position]);
 Picasso.with(activity).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `activity` context here

```
 Picasso.with(activity).load(filepath[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);
```

Comment: use activity.getApplicationContext()

Comment: After I writed this , it saying : Non-static method getApplicationContext() cannot be referenced from a static context ...

Answer (score 1):

In your getView() method

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        GridItem item = mGridData.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitle()));

        Picasso.with(context).load(filepath[position]).into(holder.imageView);
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

NOTE:

1.Make sure you are passing a file if the path to image is local.
2.pass the context from the activity where you call the adapter like `SampleActivity.this`

and try changing the Activity object to Context object in the adapter constructor

For more details on how to load a grid view with images from the server check[Grid Sample](http://javatechig.com/android/download-and-display-image-in-android-gridview)

Comment: Thank you very much @George Thomas !